# Cookies, how to configure on Ubuntu 12

Tags: firefox

I see no way to open up the browser and go in and configuring the cookie settings.  Any one know how to do this with Ubuntu 12 edition.

Comment: 12? As in 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

To get to custom cookie options in Ubuntu's included Firefox, you have to enable custom history settings:

1. Click the menu button.
2. Select preferences.
3. Choose privacy on the menu to the left.
4. Under history you will see: *Firefox will: **Remember History***. Change the **Remember History** option to **Use Custom Settings for History**.
5. Now a new option appears: **Accept cookies from sites**. Change the options under this to whatever you like. When your done, just close the tab.

If you need any other help with this, let me know, as I am happy to help.